# Can older-versioned iOS users browse apps exclusive to latest iOS? (e.g iOS5 users see iOS6 apps in App Store)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I'm planning to make my app an iOS6 only release.
I'm curious though, will older-versioned iOS users (iOS5 etc) still be able to browse and search for my app in the App Store? Will going iOS6-exclusive limit my exposure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you set the target deployment OS as 6, users on 5.1 or earlier will not see your app when using the App Store app on their device, as the App Store filters based on the target OS. However, they *will* be able to see it and download it when browsing the App Store via iTunes on their desktop, but they won't be able to run it on their device.

My recommendation: unless your app makes use of things exclusively available for iOS 6 (such as Passbook), make your app with a minimum target OS of 5.1. I'd reckon there are still a lot of users who are hesitant to upgrade to iOS 6 because of Maps alone.

Comment: Very good points, and depending on the app you might want to go even earlier than that. There are a "lot" of iPhone 3G and 3GS users on versions of OS 3.x and 4.x.

Comment: Thanks for this. Important to know especially for standalone apps. This particular app requires a larger desktop admin system in conjunction as it functions as the frontend so IOS version requirements doesn't hinder its audience as it's a very planned and deliberate installation.